# How should I go about adding social login with facebook and google plus in my Jhipster generated app?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have a Jhipster generated code and I am using Mongodb as database. I want to implement login with Facebook and google plus. This should work over rest apis on mobile as well. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread comment for discussion about social sign on with jhipster and a sample app. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/1649#issuecomment-118714100